# RecyclerView gets overlayed after changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, screen-orientation

When I change the screen orientation from vertical to horizontal and then back again the RecyclerView is redrawn and overlays the old one (you can see it between the cardviews):

[image]

**Question:** How can I suppress that behavior so Android will always reuse the RecyclerView that was created at the beginning?

fragment XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:lib="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/maschine_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/maschine_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/maschineCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/machinelistcontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_cloud_sync_maschinen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud_sync_white_48dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
        app:rippleColor="#00ffff"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using Fragment?

Comment: @4k3R : yes, I am using a fragment that is containing the RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is placed inside the machinelistcontainer

Comment: Well that exactly is where the issue is, your Fragment is inflated again over the previous fragment, I would recommend to do some checks to see if the fragment is already inflated, and if so don't inflate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your activity's `onCreate()` method, check if the activity is newly started or is it being re-created by the system. Add your fragment to it only if it isn't being re-created.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    .....

    // If savedInstanceState is null, it means that the activity is freshly created
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.machinelistcontainer, new MyFragment())
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml add the android:configChanges attrs

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and then you can handle the changes in onConfigurationChanged() in Activity java code like

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

See it in [android:configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) and [Handling Runtime Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)